# ReactJS: Getting an error while starting the server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack, yarn-lock.json

```
$ yarn start

Failed to compile.

Cannot read property 'compilation' of undefined

error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
error Command failed with signal "SIGTERM".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
ERROR: "start-js" exited with 1.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS. Sometimes it worked usually after a restart, I have matched all the node, npm and yarn version its fine. I have tried removing the `node_modules`. And sometimes its also show this error.

```
{ [Error: EPIPE: broken pipe, write] errno: -32, code: 'EPIPE', syscall: 'write' }
```

In `package.json scripts`

```
"start-js": "react-scripts start",
"start": "HTTPS=true PORT=8100 REACT_APP_OPEN_TO_URL=https://xyz.University.com/localhost npm-run-all -p watch-css start-js",
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install this plugin specify your webpack version

```
npm install --save-dev uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@1
```

For more info you can refer this url https://github.com/webpack-contrib/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/issues/360